# GridView's Automatic paging doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

According to my book all that is needed to start using automatic paging is to set GridView.AllowPaging to true. But when I try to navigate to another page, I get *GridView fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled exception*. I then have to create event handler for PageIndexChanging event, but then when I navigate to next page, GridView doesn’t display anything.

Q1 - What am I doing wrong?

Q2 - Book is written for Asp.Net 3.5, but none of the behavior described above is mentioned by the author?! Any thoughts why my GridView behaves so differently?

thanx

EDIT:

I'm embarassed to say, but reason it didn't work is because I forgot to remove the line

```
if(IsPostBack) GridView.DataSourceID="";
```

Sorry for taking your time and thanx for helping me

Comment: lol, yeah that would do it too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you post back, you'll have to rebind the data to the gridview.

You may also need to set the page number like:

```
GridView1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
```

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while, but don't you have to set the page and rebind your data?  From memory, something like ...

```
gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
// Rebind Grid
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ObjectDataSource as your GridView's data source, you don't have to do those code-behind methods - it's all handled for free.